# get object variables in abstract class

Tags: php, reflection, abstract-class, json

I have a abstract class which implements the `JsonSerializable` Interface.

**version 1:**

```
abstract class MyBase implements JsonSerializable
{
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        var_dump(get_object_vars($this));
        // ...
    }
}

class MyClass extends MyBase
{
    private $id;
    private $name;
}
```

so `json_encode(new MyClass())` returns an empty array:

> array(0) { }

**version 2:**

```
abstract class MyBase implements JsonSerializable
{
    abstract public function jsonSerialize();
}

class MyClass extends MyBase
{
    private $id;
    private $name;

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        var_dump(get_object_vars($this));
        // ...
    }
}
```

so `json_encode(new MyClass())` returns an array like:

> array(12) {   ["id"]=>   int(1)   ["name"]=>   string(1) "name" }

why does my solution 1 not working like my solution 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the properties are private!

`var_dump(get_object_vars($this));` will get your the properties accessible from that context.

Private members are accessible only from the class in which they were defined in